# How to Extract distinct Month Name from Database

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

need some help with Django Queryset Functions:

I have a model with this structure:

```
class Transacao(models.Model):
    TIPO_TRANSACAO = (
        ('D', 'Debito'),
        ('C', 'Credito'),
    )
    nome = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=20)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TIPO_TRANSACAO, default='D')
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    data = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
```

And I need to implement a "Filter" Function in my view in order to select all the "Transactions" splitted by Month. For that, I didn't want to `hardcode` all Months names in my view, so I would like to retrieve the Month's name for every Transaction, ordered by the 'date' field.

Any clue on a good way to perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is Django's methods of [dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#dates) and [datetimes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes)

```
Transacao.objects.all.datetimes('data', 'month')
```

or

```
[d.month for m in Transacao.objects.all().datetimes('data', 'month')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to change a little bit in order to work with my code:

`Transacao.objects.all().dates('data', 'month')`

Thanks again!